# Overlay with Text - After a certain time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove the button instead. The code activates automatically After the visitors stop clicking the mouse on the page for 30 seconds

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">Where  you gone?</div>
</div>


  <button onclick="on()">I want to remove this button and make the icon activate automatically after a specified time</button>
</div>
```

I want to remove the button instead. The code activates automatically After the visitors stop clicking the mouse on the page for 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`

Example using `4000`ms:

```js
var EL_overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var timeoutOverlay = null;

function on() {
  EL_overlay.style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  EL_overlay.style.display = "none";
  clearTimeout(timeoutOverlay);          // Clear existing timeout
  timeoutOverlay = setTimeout(on, 4000); // and start a new one
}

// Keep clicking to reset ongoing timeout.
// If you stop clicking, a notification will appear after 4 sec
document.body.addEventListener('click', off); 
off(); // Start the first timeout....
```

```css
html, body {height: 100%;}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="text">Where  you gone?</div>
</div>
```

and don't forget to add `html, body {height: 100%;}`